# How to display product categories and number of sales on WooCommerce

Tags: categories, plugins

I am currently working on a WooCommerce site.I managed to set it up,do some configuration according to my plan.Now i want to display product categories alongside each products in product catalog,and also want to display how many time the product has been sold too.

I have done some searching and found this code,which displays product categories,but i want to display category with link to it.

```
 <?php
 $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
 $parents = get_the_terms($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') );

 echo "<div class='product-cat'>";
 echo "In"." "." ";
 foreach( $parents as $parent ) {
 echo $parent->name;
 }
?>
```

Please help out on this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking in the Codex for answers.  You will find that [`get_term_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) creates links to terms.

```
foreach( $parents as $parent ) {
    echo get_term_link( $parent );
}
```